# Spacing between list items beamer

Tags: beamer

What could be the reason that the second item doesn't have the same line spacing as the first one?

If the nested enumeration is removed; we get the expected results. Otherwise, line spacing is varying.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{XYZ}
  \begin{itemize}
    {\fontsize{16pt}{30}\selectfont
      \item xx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx \{x, x\}.
      \item xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxx:}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item S
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly what your problem is, but try adding an empty line right before the nested enumeration environment:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{XYZ}
  \begin{itemize}
    {\fontsize{16pt}{30}\selectfont
      \item xx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx \{x, x\}.
      \item xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxx:}

      \begin{enumerate}
        \item S
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

That fixes the spacing between the lines of the second item of the outer enumeration. The spacing between the first and second line of the first item in the outer enumeration looks odd since you added the `\{x, x\}` which increases the line spacing – but that did not change when I removed the nested enumeration, so I assume you didn't refer to that.